# Hover over and find the text on a diabled element

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Is it possible to hover over a disabled element in Cypress. I am getting error that the element is disabled.

Comment: have you tried `.click({ force: true })` https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Invoke

Comment: Please add the code along with the error message that you are getting.